# Item is Saving in sqlite database again and again

Tags: android, string, android-sqlite, repeat

I am trying to save a value in sqlite database only if my desired condition satisfied but it is saving the value in database even if the condition is satisfied and it doesnot stop.

this is my code

```
int asas = 0;
       if (list!= null) {
         for (int i1 = 0; i1 < list.size(); i1++) {

           String s= list.get(i1);

           while (msgBody.toUpperCase().contains(s.toUpperCase()) && !contactExists(context, msg_from)) {

               asas++;
             if (asas>=3)
             {
                screenMessage(context, msg_from, msg_from, msgBody, msgDate); //saving value in this table
             }

             if (asas <3 && !contactExists(context, msg_from)) {


                screenMessagee(context, msg_from, msg_from, msgBody, msgDate); //saving value in this table

             break;
              }
             break;
           }
         }
       }
```

Now let me explain my code. I have a listview containing different items stored in it. now what I am doing here is that I am checking that if the string given by user which is named as "msgBody" contains those listview items stored. Thats why I use int asas=0 so that when string given by user then while condition checks how many items of that listview are in the string provided by user. If the string contains 3 or more items then it is saved in specific table. If string contains less than 3 items then it is saved in another table.
Now the problem I am facing is that if the provided string contains lets example 5 items then the provided string will be saved in this table 3 times

```
screenMessage(context, msg_from, msg_from, msgBody, msgDate);
```

What i figure out is that it may happening because while condition when reach to 3 items stored then it saved the value in database but as the provided string contains 5 items so while condition doesnot stopped and saved the value two more times until the condition is satsified for all 5 items.
Please Help what to do to stop the condition if 3 items found and value must be saved only one time in database table

Comment: Store item when you create database!

Comment: but i want to store after that condition satisfied

Comment: Then create application variable flag

Comment: i did not understand what are u saying please can you correct my code?

Comment: I don't really understand you code, the condition aren't optimize and the name of methods aren't helpful. Is screenMessage is the one inserting in database ?

Comment: Yes if condition satisfied then screenMessage is saving that provided string by user in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you want to count the number of times words stored in your list occurs in a particular string, then store it in one of two database tables depending on if its less than 3 or not.

I dont really understand your code but try this:

```
int asas = 0;
   if (list!= null) {
     for (int i1 = 0; i1 < list.size(); i1++) {

       String s= list.get(i1);


       if(msgBody.toUpperCase().contains(s.toUpperCase()) && !contactExists(context, msg_from)){

           asas++;
       }


   }
     if(asas>0){
    if(asas<3)
    {
        screenMessagee(context, msg_from, msg_from, msgBody, msgDate); //saving value in this table
    }

    else{

        screenMessage(context, msg_from, msg_from, msgBody, msgDate); //saving value in this table
    }
     }
```

Comment: Yes exactly what i need to do as u said. Lemme apply your code

Comment: I dont know what to say but you didnot understand the code and still it works like a charm. Thankyou so much you are genious